# Cannot implicitly convert type decimal? to OrdersList, are you missing a cast

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I did a lot of research on stack overflow and none of the answers helped me, i have the following code

```
public IEnumerable<OrdersList> GetOrdersList(string code)
{
    return Repository.Find<OrdersList>(x => x.ProductTitle != "" && x.Code == code);
}
```

and it works perfectly but now because i have a view in my MSSQL 2014 database that is being used my multiple functions i cant really do much in that view and so i have to do some transforming with LINQ, what i need is to filter out orders that have the highest price and group them by ProductTitle and Code.

The data i have:

[image: the data i have]

when i try the following LINQ syntax:

```
public IEnumerable<OrdersList> GetOrdersList(string code)
{
    return Repository.Find<OrdersList>(x => x.ProductTitle != "" && x.Code == code)
                     .GroupBy(x => x.MaxPrice);
}
```

it instantly gives me the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type decimal? to OrdersList, are you missing a cast

what I'm thinking is that after i do a GroupBy it returns me only the MaxPrice as a single record and that's why it gives me the error, what i need to achieve is this:

[image]

I tried adding a `GroupBy(x => x.MaxPrice).Select(s => s)` and it still throws the same error at design time, Any input on how i can achieve my result would be welcome, thank you in advance.

Entity Framework Generated Model:

```
class OrdersList
{
    public decimal? MaxPrice { get; set; }
    public string? Supplier { get; set; }
    public string ProductTitle { get; set; }
    public string? Code { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Group by in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq)

Comment: I looked there and maybe it could help me but still i don't know how to achieve the result i want only using LINQ.

Comment: So you want to group (`group by`) or filter (`where`)? Do you have a regular SQL query you want to achieve with LINQ?

Comment: these fields are only as demo data in the actual table there are about 25 fields so i will have to write all them in the select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find a maximum price within the orders having the same Title and Code:

```
from o in orders
where o.Supplier != null &&
      o.ProductTitle != null &&
      o.Code != null &&
      o.MaxPrice != null
group o by new { o.ProductTitle, o.Code } into g
select new
{
    ProductTitle = g.Key.ProductTitle,
    Code = g.Key.Code,
    MaxPrice = g.Max(x => x.MaxPrice)
};
```

What as extension methods chain looks like this:

```
orders.Where(o => o.Supplier != null &&
                  o.ProductTitle != null &&
                  o.Code != null &&
                  o.MaxPrice != null)
      .GroupBy(g => new { o.ProductTitle, o.Code })
      .Select(g => new
          {
              ProductTitle = g.Key.ProductTitle,
              Code = g.Key.Code,
              MaxPrice = g.Max(x => x.MaxPrice)
          });
```

Comment: Could i get the same query in a methods form? :)

Comment: Nice setting up my environment  as im at home and will try it out, thanks a million :)

Comment: me to launched MSSQL developing the table and will shortly go to Visual Studio will post back the answer in ~15min

Comment: It works as expected, only that you forgot to add .ToList() at the end bu everything else works as expected, is there any way to not write down all the column in select? because in my real table i have like 25+ of them :)

Comment: @AirWolf: I prefer to use `ToArray()` because you aren't going to `Add()` anything to the result, I suppose.

Comment: @AirWolf: about fields I'm not sure because it makes unclear what are you trying to achieve,